# cases when strcpy can be use but strcat cannot

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy, strcat

Main question is: should I ever use strcpy (from cstring library)?

I often use strcat instead of strcpy in pgms like:

```
char arr[10];
arr[0] = '\0';
strcat(arr, "hey!"); // alternatively strcpy(arr, "hey!");
```

I cannot think of cases where strcpy could not be replaced by strcat. Are there any?

Comment: When one does not initialise the string with a null string in the first place

Comment: I you are going to make that code obfuscation a bad habit, you can use strcat instead of strcpy

Comment: @DieterLücking - Try switching the last bit

Comment: `strcpy` and `strcat` carry different semantics, although by coincidence they may produce identical results. Code is more readable if you convey as much information as you can. Using `strcpy` to copy, and `strcat` to append strings is recommended.

Comment: Q: "I often use `-=` and `+=` instead of ordinary assignment. Eg. `i -= i, i += 42;` I think I could always replace `i = 42;` with the above. Can you think of a reason I shouldn't?". A: Yes, I can; several. But if you're seriously asking that question, my answers are probably going to fall on deaf ears.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you like to use `strcat` when `strcpy` would do?

Comment: Note that `strcat()` is a very dangerous function as it can lead to very inefficient code. Using multiple `strcat()`s on the same string is often done and it's very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you. Crystal clear now.

Comment: "*I often use `strcat` instead of `strcpy` ...*" Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any cases where `strcpy` can't be replaced by `strcat` (after setting the initial character of the target to `'\0'`)? I don't think so.

Does that mean you should always use `strcat` when `strcpy` would do the job? Absolutely not.

`strcpy` makes no assumptions about the initial contents of the target array.

`strcat` requires the target to contain a terminating `'\0'` null character -- and if it's not in the initial position, it will scan for it, to and possibly beyond the end of the array.

It's true that

```
strcpy(dest, source);
```

is equivalent to

```
dest[0] = '\0';
strcat(dest, source);
```

so you *can* always use `strcat` instead of `strcpy`. That doesn't mean you should.

`strcpy` is commonly used to replace the contents of an array:

```
char s[100] = "hello, world";
...
strcpy(s, "goodbye, cruel world");
```

Replacing that last line with:

```
s[0] = '\0';
strcat(s, "goodbye, cruel world");
```

would just make the code more verbose and more difficult to read.

If you want to *copy* a string into an array, use `strcpy`. If you want to *concatenate* a string onto an existing one, use `strcat`.

Answer (score 2):

From doc of `strcat`:

> Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The
>   terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first
>   character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of
>   the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

so destination has to be null terminated. This is not required for `strcpy`.

And as you do it, indeed it would be more readable to use `strcpy` in your case, rather than manually assigning 0 to first element of array and using `strcat`.